# Scroll to top of a control with ScrollViewer in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, scrollviewer

I've got an MVVM Light WPF app in Visual Studio 2015. A `ScrollViewer` contains the contents in `MainWindow.xaml`, which in turn contains a `TabControl`. One of the `TabItem` controls contains a `DataGrid`. When the user clicks a row of the `DataGrid`, we show the `tcEmployeeDetails` `TabControl`, using the `SelectedEmployee` property on the view model bound to the `SelectedItem` of the data grid:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Border>
        <DockPanel>
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem>
                    <!-- Search controls go here... -->

                    <DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">
                        <!-- DataGrid columns here... -->
                    </DataGrid>

                    <!-- How do I scroll the ScrollViewer to here? -->
                    <TabControl x:Name="tcEmployeeDetails">
                        <!-- TabItems go here... -->
                    </TabControl>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem>
                    <!-- Other items here... -->
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
</ScrollViewer>
```

How can I scroll the `ScrollViewer` to the top of `tcEmployeeDetails` when the user has selected a row of the `DataGrid`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add a property to your vm:

```
private double _scrollViewerVerticalOffset;
public double ScrollViewerVerticalOffset 
{
    get { return _scrollViewerVerticalOffset; }
    set { _scrollViewerVerticalOffset = value; }
}
```

Bind this property to the scrollviewer's `VerticalOffset`.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalOffset="{Binding ScrollViewerVerticalOffset}">
```

And modify your setter for `SelectedEmployee`:

```
public double _scrollViewerVerticalOffset 
{
   get { ... }
   set {
           if (this.SelectedEmployee != value)  
                  ScrollViewerVerticalOffset = 0;
       }
 }
```

Comment: `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` is a readonly property.

Comment: @JokeHuang It's interesting that this is just now coming to light. Are you still looking for a solution? I'll attempt to edit answer with a working one, I just don't have time at the moment.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling it is not working code.  Please edit the answer.